# How much health does Symmetra's Photon Barrier have?

Tags: overwatch

In the new update, Symmetra had a (kind of) remake. One of those changes was to her `E`ability, where it would spawn a mini-Reinhardt barrier charging forward.

What is the health of the barrier?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The barrier [reportedly](http://www.pcgamer.com/symmetra-new-ultimate-ability-rework-overwatch/) has 1000 hit points. Though as she's still in the PTR those numbers aren't final. That's why they haven't updated the [wiki](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Symmetra) yet.

Comment: 1000 hit what!? I can already see 100 Symetras in every game if that does not change..

Comment: @Alex No one's playing no limits .. It takes forever to get queued in that. Everywhere else you can only have 1 Symetra .. Plus the shield isn't at all that good.

Comment: It sounds OP, haven't played it yet so I'll trust you

Comment: @Alex it's a sheild that moves foward and which isn't protecting feets. It's not like she could control it at will just like Reinhardt.

Comment: Right, 1000 is a lot, but it's constantly moving forward. Enemies can run through it.

Comment: It is handy for protecting against some ultimates that suddenly appear, like McCree's ultimate, or D.Va ultimate.